# How to run my local application in a container

Tags: docker, selenium-grid, selenium-docker

I have built my application locally and accessible locally. Something like 'http://localhost:4200/admin/login' works fine.

An i have my automation suite that i want to execute in a selenium grid environment. So I created a hub and node and they are interconnected.

When i run any global applications like google.com etc... then those sites are accessible in selenium node container and they are working fine.

But when i run my suite pointing to local, they are not executing in the node container. How can i access my local deployed application in Node container?

I started my hub using
'docker run -d -p 4545:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub'

and started my node as
'docker run -d -P --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome-debug'

Comment: Please explain how you start the containers. Both hub and application run on docker containers?

Comment: @leopal I updated post how to launch hub and node. How can i verify my application is available in a node container?

Comment: Hey @Uday, I recommend you use docker-compose instead 'link' containers, on the wiki you have the instructions: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Docker-Compose, and you can access using http://localhost:4444 (for example)

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Thanks, but my question is still ON. I hope compose will not help my purpose. I need show can i access my local application in node container?